# "Blind" / "Headless" input to a VNC session

Tags: vnc, input, headless

**Is it possible to configure VNC such that:**

- mouse & keyboard input is delivered from client to server
- no display capture is performed, and no display data is sent from server to client

?

The host machine is running *OS X.* The client machine is running *Windows 7*.

**Background:**

Without going into too much detail, I just need a blank "surface"/window on the client to capture and transmit input. The output from the server I view on a monitor directly connected at the same desk. I have noticed that CPU usage often spikes on the host machine and input latency suffers. I want to reduce input latency (reduce host CPU % spikes) by making the VNC session "write" but not "read", in some sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by installing [Vine Server VNC](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine/) instead of using the VNC server built into OS X. In the Vine Server GUI I specified the following command line arguments

```
-noupdates -deferupdate 200
```

When I connect with my VNC client (UltraVNC), I now essentially get a giant blank window as my input surface, and in OS X I see less than 1% CPU utilization from Vine Server. Success!

Answer (score 1):

Try [win2vnc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win2vnc/).  I think this does what you're describing.